# How to skip appending some condition in map scala?

Tags: scala, collections, immutability

I have a situation in which I need to create a map from a collection by applying some filter inside like given in the code below:

````scala
//Say I have a list
//I don't have to apply filter function ...

val myList = List(2,3,4,5)

val evenList = myList.map(x=>{
if ( x is even) x
else 0
}
//And the output is : List(2,0,4,0)
//The output actually needed was List(2,4) without applying filter on top like - ```myList.filter```
//I have objects instead of numbers of a case class so the output becomes :List(object1, None, object2, None)
But actual output needed was : List(object1,object2)
````

//The updated scenario

```scala
val basket = List(2,4,5,6)
case class Apple(name:Option[String],size:Option[Int])

val listApples: List[Apple] = basket.map(x=>{

  val r = new scala.util.Random
  val size = r.nextInt(10)

  if(x%2!=0){
    Apple(None,None)
  }
  else Apple(Some("my-apple"),Some(size))
})
```

Current Output :

```scala
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(2))
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(0))
Apple(None,None)
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(4))
```

```scala
Expected was :
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(2))
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(0))
Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(4))
```

Comment: //I have objects instead of numbers of a case class so the output becomes :List(object1, None, object2, None)
But actual output needed was : List(object1,object2)  <- Why not simply use .flatten /flatMap ?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Add a real example with objects.

Comment: updated the scenario @GamingFelix

Comment: updated the scenario @pme

Comment: @pinku that makes more sense +1;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `collect` best suits your case. It takes a partial function as an argument and only if that function matches then the element is transformed and added to result:

```
val myList = List(2,3,4,5)

case class Wrapper(i: Int)

val evenList = myList.collect{
  case x if x % 2 == 0 => Wrapper(x)
}
```

In this case only `2` and `4` will be wrapped inside `Wrapper`:

```
List(Wrapper(2), Wrapper(4))
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but why not just use a `filter` directly:

```
val myList = List(2,3,4,5)

myList.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
```

If you want to have the *Filter* as a function:

```
def even(n:Int) = n % 2 == 0

myList.filter(even)
```

**After question update**, here the difference between `filter` and `collect`:

**Filter:**

```
  myList
    .filter(even) 
    .map(s => Apple(Some("my-apple"),Some(s)))
```

**Collect:**

```
myList
    .collect{ case s if(even(s)) => Apple(Some("my-apple"),Some(s))}
```

Both return `List(Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(2)), Apple(Some(my-apple),Some(4)))`

So the only difference is that you can do both steps at once with `collect`.

However for me to separate these 2 steps is mostly more readable.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense yeah, simply using filter will filter out what he doesn't need. Have my vote

Comment: and he's asking for this List(object1, None, object2, None) to become this List(object1,object2), so I believe your answer + .flatten should do it?

Comment: @GamingFelix as long as you don't need a `map` as well then `collect` would be the most elegant way;).

Comment: Will collect also flatten it? Never really used it. Reading up on it now :)

Comment: @GamingFelix that is a bit the confusing about the question - I interpreted it like the starting list would be already `List(object1, None, object2, None) ` - so all that is different would be the filter function.

Comment: @GamingFelix I don't think `flatten` is needed at all - but for that the question must be clarified.

Comment: Alright, seemed like an easy way to get rid of None. But you are right that the question should be clarified